# Include file from ignored folder in flow config

Tags: flowtype

Is there a way to include a file from an ignored folder. In my case I have a tools folder that should be ignored, but the one file to stub `txt` files should be used from flow:

```
[ignore]
.*/tools/*
[include]
./tools/flow/textStub.js
[options]
strip_root=true
module.name_mapper.extension='txt' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/tools/flow/textStub.js'
```

Unfortunately the above does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Flow docs](https://flowtype.org/docs/advanced-configuration.html#_):

> Ignores are processed AFTER includes. If you include and ignore a file it will be ignored

However, you might be able to work around it by declaring your types for `textStub` as a lib:

```
[lib]
./flow-typed/tools/textStub.js
```

It's a bit of double-work, since you'll have to maintain the declarations files separately from your code, but it might accomplish what you need.